# TYPO3 7.6 gzip compression

Tags: typo3, gzip, typo3-7.6.x

I'm trying to get compression to work on a Mittwald vHost Server.
But if I activate `config.compressJs = 1` or `config.compressCss = 1` in Typoscript the Browser can't read the JS/CSS anymore?
Does anyone know the right (htaccess) settings? I'm working on a Mittwald vMangedServer.

And I've activated in the install Tool $`TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['compressionLevel'] = '5';`

This is a part of my .htaccess  file:

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(php.*|phtml)\."> 
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L] 
 </FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^de/(.*)  /$1 [L,R=301]



<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/css" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
AddEncoding gzip .gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>



    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
            application/javascript \
            application/json \
            application/ld+json \
            application/manifest+json \
            application/rdf+xml \
            application/rss+xml \
            application/schema+json \
            application/vnd.geo+json \
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
            application/x-font-ttf \
            application/x-javascript \
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
            application/xhtml+xml \
            application/xml \
            font/eot \
            font/opentype \
            image/bmp \
            image/svg+xml \
            image/vnd.microsoft.icon \
            image/x-icon \
            text/cache-manifest \
            text/css \
            text/html \
            text/javascript \
            text/plain \
            text/vcard \
            text/vnd.rim.location.xloc \
            text/vtt \
            text/x-component \
            text/x-cross-domain-policy \
            text/xml
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    # Data interchange
    AddType application/atom+xml                        atom
    AddType application/json                            json map topojson
    AddType application/ld+json                         jsonld
    AddType application/rss+xml                         rss
    AddType application/vnd.geo+json                    geojson
    AddType application/xml                             rdf xml

    # JavaScript
    AddType application/javascript                      js

    # Manifest files
    AddType application/manifest+json                   webmanifest
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache

    # Media files

    AddType audio/mp4                                   f4a f4b m4a
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg opus
    AddType image/bmp                                   bmp
    AddType image/svg+xml                               svg svgz
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType video/mp4                                   f4v f4p m4v mp4
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv
    AddType image/x-icon                                cur ico

    # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/font-woff2                      woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf

    # Other
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-bb-appworld                   bbaw
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType text/vcard                                  vcard vcf
    AddType text/vnd.rim.location.xloc                  xloc
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this at Mittwald.

TypoScript

```
config.compressCss = 1
config.compressJs = 1
```

.htaccess as first block before any rewriting

```
### Begin: Compression ###

# Compressing resource files will save bandwidth and so improve loading speed especially for users
# with slower internet connections. TYPO3 can compress the .js and .css files for you.
# *) Uncomment the following lines and
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 for the Backend
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 together with the TypoScript properties
#    config.compressJs and config.compressCss for GZIP compression of Frontend JS and CSS files.

<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/css" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
AddEncoding gzip .gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
            application/javascript \
            application/json \
            application/ld+json \
            application/manifest+json \
            application/rdf+xml \
            application/rss+xml \
            application/schema+json \
            application/vnd.geo+json \
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
            application/x-font-ttf \
            application/x-javascript \
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
            application/xhtml+xml \
            application/xml \
            font/eot \
            font/opentype \
            image/bmp \
            image/svg+xml \
            image/vnd.microsoft.icon \
            image/x-icon \
            text/cache-manifest \
            text/css \
            text/html \
            text/javascript \
            text/plain \
            text/vcard \
            text/vnd.rim.location.xloc \
            text/vtt \
            text/x-component \
            text/x-cross-domain-policy \
            text/xml
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

### End: Compression ###
```

Install-Tool (LocalConfiguration.php)

```
[BE][compressionLevel] = 9 
[FE][compressionLevel] = 9
```

Comment: Works now, this was the important Information:  _as first block before any rewriting_